# How to open up all .text files with the same name?

Tags: php

Okay so let's say I have a folder and in a folder I have a ton of text files.
TextLog11564.txt
TextLog21564.txt
TextLog3456.txt

and so on, how would I open all of them, get the contents, and display them on the page? I know how to open a text file and read stuff from it but is there a way to open up all text files that start with "TextLog"? Instead of having to call them each one by one in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) for this:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("TextLog*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

```
foreach (glob("TextLog*") as $filename) {
  //
}
```